# Extract number from column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a lot of address data in (mostly) this format:

```
Karl-Reimann-Ring 13, 99087 Erfurt
Markttwiete 2, 23611 Bad Schwartau
Hüxstraße 55, 23552 Lübeck
Bunsenstraße 1c, 24145 Kiel
```

and my goal is to extract the zip code.

I copied a formula from a website, which i dont really understand:

```
=VERWEIS(9^9;1*TEIL(E2861&"#";SPALTE(2860:2860);6))
```

```
VERWEIS = LOOKUP,
TEIL = MID,
SPALTE = COLUMN
```

This formula seems to work 99% of the time, also for the ones above, but for some i get weird results.

```
Kurt-Schumacher-Straße 56, 55124 Mainz --> 44340
Kleine Früchtstraße 6, 55130 Mainz --> 44346
Bahnstraße 1, 55128 Mainz --> 44344
```

All with 'Mainz' are wrong and start with 44xxx

But when i increase the last argument from 6 to 7 it seems to work.

Do somebody know, how i can impove this formula to get always the correct zip code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the formula will return the last "number" which is constructed of 6 character strings starting at every character in the string.

The last substring that can be interpreted numerically (in the `55424 Mainz` address) is actually `24 Mai`.  German Excel will parse that into `24 Mai 2021` which, as a number, will be 44340.

One modification you can make to your formula, to prevent that from happening, would be to add a comma after the zipcode.  eg:

```
=LOOKUP(9^9;1*MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1;" ";",") & "#";COLUMN(2860:2860);6))
```

Another option would be to use `FILTERXML` where you can separate by spaces, and then return the last numeric node:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(A1;" ";"</s><s>") & "</s></t>";"//s[number(.) = number(.)][last()]")
```

Comment: `FILTERXML()` will be best choice.

Comment: upvoted for `filterxml` use.  Can you please explain a bit more of this syntax

Comment: @AnilGoyal see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml) from jvdv and also the [w3schools xPath tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). The formula before the xPath is merely to construct the `xml`.